# Cannot get access to Google Calendar API via Service Account

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I'm trying to retrieve my own free/busy calendar via a simple POST call in Java, and I'm running into access errors.  Basically I'm getting a 404, notFound error like so:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
 "timeMin": "2019-05-28T13:00:00.000Z",
 "timeMax": "2019-05-28T21:00:00.000Z",
 "calendars": {
  "me@mycompany.com": {
   "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "notFound"
    }
   ],
   "busy": []
  }
 }
}
```

The code is fairly straightforward.  I can get exactly what I need if I use a bearer token from the OAuth Playground, everything works just fine.  Here's my relevant code:

```
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResource("...a59.json")).getFile());

        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
                .fromStream(new FileInputStream(file))
                .createScoped(CalendarScopes.all());

        credential.refreshToken();
        String accessToken = credential.getAccessToken();
```

The `accessToken` value I get back results in the response above.

For my service account, I have created it within a project that has the Calendar API enabled.  I've also granted it the role of `Project Owner` so that it has full access to the settings in the project.

I'm sure this is something small and simple with my Service Account configuration, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to figure this one out myself.  Seems that my service account was setup correctly, but the permissions I added were not.  For the record, here's what I wanted:

1. Get read-only access to a calendar.
2. Be able to retrieve the calendar of any user in my organization.

I had created the service account, made sure it had Domain Wide Delegation authorization, added the Calendar and Admin APIs to my project that holds the service account, but I couldn't get it to work without adding my service account to the calendar per @Alex Baban's message above.

I went back to the drawing board as adding this to a few dozen accounts wasn't an ideal solution, and then I found it.  I had to add the following authorizations for my service account:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly

Hopefully this helps someone else out in the future.

Comment: These don't seem to be showing up under `roles` -> `permissions` under `IAM and Admin`

Answer (score 1):

You need one more step.

**You will need to share your calendar with your service account.**

Open the `something-something.json` file which you downloaded when creating the service account with a text editor, and you'll find the email address needed as the value of the "client_email" key/value pair.

Go to your calendar "Settings and sharing" and click on "+ Add people" button which you'll find under "Share with specific people".

---

You have likely done this, but for others, here is the full procedure to access Google Calendar with a service account: ([allow my user to add meeting in my calendar with Google Calendar API with PHP without auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242345/allow-my-user-to-add-meeting-in-my-calendar-with-google-calendar-api-with-php-wi/56250539#56250539))

Comment: Brilliant!!  This did it!  ow the next question is how can I share this across my org?  I have admin privileges for our GSuite, but I'm not 100% sure on the setting.

Comment: It's just a guess, as I don't have access or experience with the enterprise version, but try to add the service account as another user in your organization.