# Access Google calendar API (PHP)

Tags: php, api, google-api, calendar

I'm trying to access the Google Calendar API.

I have followed the instructions from @alexbaban

[allow my user to add meeting in my calendar with Google Calendar API with PHP without auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242345/allow-my-user-to-add-meeting-in-my-calendar-with-google-calendar-api-with-php-wi/56250539#56250539)

Then I tried his source code and it happened...nothing.

```
<?php
require_once './google-api-php-client-2.2.3/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly");
$client->setAuthConfig('client_credentials.json');
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

while(true) {

  foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
    echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
    echo "\n------------------------------\n\n";

    // get events 
    $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarListEntry->id);

    foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
        echo "- " . $event->getSummary() . "\n";
        echo "- " . $event->getStart()->getDateTime() . "\n\n";
    }

  }

  $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();

  if ($pageToken) {
    $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
    $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
?>
```

**No Error. No Output. Nothing.**

To be sure that it is not due to an outdated version, I also tried "google-api-php-client-2.4.0", but I got the same result.

Can someone give me a little tip where I have to look for the error?

Apparently I'm just too stupid for that.

Comment: `while(true)` if this is always going to be true, what is it's use?

Comment: Run `var_dump($calendarList->getItems());` and see if anything is output, you'll want to run this just after `$calendarList` is set.

Comment: var_dump($calendarList->getItems());

--->    array(0) { }

Comment: That'll be why nothing is output, the items you're looping through don't exist.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But why is everything empty? At least there should be something in there.

Comment: why are you running your code in an infinite loop?

Comment: Because it is stated in the example. I assumed that an example worked. If so, you can still optimize, right? :-)