# Google Client for Calendar service responding with a 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, google-calendar-api, google-client

#### Target

I'm trying to integrate [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) to my company website to automate event creation upon some events.

The events will be added to a company calendar and displayed to the users, so i don't need the users to authenticate, i will not work on their own calendars.

#### What i've done

- made a OAuth 2.0 service account as described in the Google [OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) docs
- created, downloaded and added the credentials file to my project, and added its path to the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`;
- followed the [docs example to authorize my requests using the service account](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php) and the [docs to create events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events).
  Here's a short version of my sourcecode:

  ```
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("XXX");
  $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR); // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
  $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

  $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

  $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(/* array with event data */);
  $calendarId = /* calendar id taken from calendar Settings and Sharing on calendar.google.com*/;

  $event      = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
  ```

  Compared to the example (lines 43:52) I didn't manually check for the credential files but gone straight for `useApplicationDefaultCredentials()`.

#### The error

The logged errror from my code is

```
[2020-10-19 14:29:19] local.ERROR: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
 {"userId":2,"exception":"[object] (Google_Service_Exception(code: 404): {
 \"error\": {
  \"errors\": [
   {
    \"domain\": \"global\",
    \"reason\": \"notFound\",
    \"message\": \"Not Found\"
   }
  ],
  \"code\": 404,
  \"message\": \"Not Found\"
 }
}
 at /var/www/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:123)
[stacktrace]
```

It looks like it is calling the wrong api endpoint since a `404` is a `page not found` response.

**Calendar ID**
Just to be clear, here is where i taken the calendar id
[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, service accounts do not have their own calendars, so they need to be granted access to a specific organization in order to create/read events.

If this is for an internal application (and you are an administrator for your organization), you can follow the steps under [Delegating Authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) to grant your service account access to the calendars for your organization:

> Then, a super administrator of the G Suite domain must complete the following steps:
>
> 1. From your G Suite domain’s [Admin console](https://admin.google.com/), go to Main menu menu > Security > API Controls.
> 2. In the Domain wide delegation pane, select Manage Domain Wide Delegation.
>    Click Add new.
> 3. In the Client ID field, enter the service account's Client ID. You can find your service account's client ID in the [Service accounts page](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts).
> 4. In the OAuth scopes (comma-delimited) field, enter the list of scopes that your application should be granted access to. For example, if your application needs domain-wide full access to the Google Drive API and the Google Calendar API, enter: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`.
> 5. Click Authorize.

You'll also need to follow the steps to impersonate a specific user under [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) in order to retrieve a token for a user that has access to the calendar in question.

If this is for an application intended to be installed by multiple organizations, you should consider using a managed OAuth service, like [Xkit](https://xkit.co) (*where I work*). Xkit in particular has a [Google Calendar Service Account connector](https://docs.xkit.co/docs/google-calendar-service-account) that abstracts away all of these steps (including a step-by-step guide for the IT admin) from you as the developer to deliver you a working access token in one API call.

As a side note, the service account example you cited uses public data from the Books API, so it does not need authorization from a user, it only needs to identify itself as an application.

Comment: Yeah, i found it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56250539/3030926), so i answered my own question but made it the wrong way, so my own answer has been downvoted and cancelled 